# Case Overriding where?

Tags: sql, join, case

Ok so i have one table with lets call it A(there are more items here):

```
  ITEMID NAME
    10001  Boat
```

I have another table lets call it B(there are more items here):

```
Itemid Price Pricetype Dimension Valid_from Valid_To
10001   10      1        Allblank 2014-10-10  2014-10-25
10001    5      2        200      2014-10-09  2014-10-20
10001    99     2        200      2014-10-08  2014-10-10
10001    20     1        Allblank 2014-10-08  2014-10-10
10001    22     2        500      2014-10-10  2014-10-19
```

Price type determines wherever item is on sale or no so i want to list the regular price at its dimension and the sales price at the dimension so the table should look like this (assuming that 1 is regular price and 2 is sale price):

```
Itemid Itemname RegularPrice DiscountPrice200 DiscountPrice500
10001    boat       10             5              22
```

I've inner joined tables, but i cant manage to manage the fields right , case statement returns a lot of duplicates on inner join. I hope i made myself clear :)

My query:

```
SELECT a.itemid,
case when b.inventdimid = '00000101_090' and (b.labelissue ='1' or b.labelissue = '2' and (b.todate > getdate() or b.todate ='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')  ) then b.amount else null end as Price500
  FROM  a
  inner join b
  on a.itemid = b.itemrelation
```

Comment: How do you choose which price goes into which columns?  For instance, why is the fourth column "5" and not "99"?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I think it depends on valid_from and valid_to columns

Comment: Yeah when i write select i write valid_to > getdate()

Comment: Post your SQL if you can.

Comment: Posted code hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT b.itemid,
       a.name,
       b.price,
       b200.price,
       b500.price
  FROM tb b
  JOIN ta a 
    ON b.itemid = a.itemid
  JOIN tb b200
    ON b.itemid = b200.itemid
   AND b200.valid_to > getdate()    
   AND b200.pricetype = 2
   AND b200.dimension = 200
  JOIN tb b500
    ON b.itemid = b500.itemid
   AND b500.valid_to > getdate()    
   AND b500.pricetype = 2
   AND b500.dimension = 500 
 WHERE b.valid_to > getdate()   
   AND b.pricetype = 1
```